# Pandas access length of group touple key with only one part of that key

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I've got a `DataFrameGroupBy` with a key that is of the structure `Hour, ID`.

I am trying to get the size of each group with each key from each hour.

Running `mygroup.size()` gives me output like:

```
   ID
0  41           3
   55          10
   56           1
   60           7
   65           1
...
23  2218         5
    2222         9
    2223         5
    2225         2
```

What I want to be able to do is filter this list so I can just get the total number in each group, based on the `Hour` part of the key (0-23)

Comment: IIUC then `mygroup.size().count(level=0)` will give you what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html#pandas.DataFrame.count) and pass `level=0`, example:

```
In [21]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,1,1,1,1],'b':[1,2,3,12,3,4],'c':np.arange(6)})
df

Out[21]:
   a   b  c
0  0   1  0
1  0   2  1
2  1   3  2
3  1  12  3
4  1   3  4
5  1   4  5

In [22]:    
gp = df.groupby(['a','b'])
gp.size()

Out[22]:
a  b 
0  1     1
   2     1
1  3     2
   4     1
   12    1
dtype: int64

In [23]:
gp.size().count(level=0)

Out[23]:
a
0    2
1    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Thank you so much